# How to calculate amplitude from spectrum()

Tags: r, fft, spectrum

I have a signal and I need to get the actual magnitude of a frequency found at `spectrum()`

Consider the following signal

```
f <- 5
n <- 500
signal <- 4*sin(2*pi*f*seq(0,10,1/n))
S.signal <- spectrum(signal, log="no")
```

Using `spectrum()` I get the following:

[image]

I can verify the amplitude of the peak using:

```
> max(S.signal$spec)
[1] 16698.45
```

How can I convert this value `16698.45` to the actual magnitude of the signal at that frequency `4` - or something close?

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between the amplitude of your signal and the amplitude of your spectrum here. The Fourier transform of a sinus is a delta function at the corresponding frequency, that is an infinitely narrow pic with an infinite amplitude.

The fact that you find a value for the amplitude of your spetrum is due to the sampling of your signal that cause a loss of information, You can see that here :

```
f <- 5
n <- 1000
signal <- 4*sin(2*pi*f*seq(0,10,1/n))
S.signal <- spectrum(signal, log="no")
max(S.signal$spec)
[1] 25261.03
```

You have better sampling, so you get a value closer to the real value of the spectrum (that is inifinity here).

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but in case it helps others. As previous answers state, it is not a question of how to convert the spectral density to an amplitude, but rather, having found a signal in our density spectra, how do we extract the amplitude at the dominant frequency. I found the custom function proposed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785142/bandpassfilter-r-using-fft/40786253#40786253) useful.

An example implementing it with original poster's example:

```
power_spec = function(y,samp.freq, ...){

  N <- length(y)
  fk <- fft(y)
  fk <- fk[2:length(fk)/2+1]
  fk <- 2*fk[seq(1, length(fk), by = 2)]/N
  freq <- (1:(length(fk)))* samp.freq/(2*length(fk))
  data.frame(amplitude = Mod(fk), freq = freq)
}

f <- 5
n <- 500
signal <- 4*sin(2*pi*f*seq(0,10,1/n))

x = power_spec(signal,samp.freq = 1/n)

plot(x$amplitude~x$freq,type='l',xlim=c(0,10))
```

We find a peak with an amplitude of 4 at f = 5.

Please up-vote the original post where this custom function came from if it helps you too!

Answer (score 0):

If your signal is really like what you mentioned in your code, a sin() function, then you should only get a impulse/peak at one location, and anywhere else is simply zero.